Error importing GA4 data tracked via Firebase: "Field customEvent is not a valid dimension"
I am encountering an issue while attempting to import data from an GA4 Analytics resource that used Firebase for tracking data on a mobile app.
When I start the import using the GA4 import tool, it gives me the following error:
customEvent:firebase_screen? Field customEvent:firebase_event_origin is not a valid dimension.
I triedo to do the normal GA4 import and the import for a mobile resource for GA4 but it gives me the same error of the invalid dimension.
I would prefer not to have to map every event/dimension from Firebase by hand.

Is there a way to correctly import Firebase-based GA4 data without needing to map each event and dimension manually?
Are there any specific configurations needed to enable this type of import from GA4 or Firebase to Matomo without compatibility issues?

I have already asked on the Matomo Forum, but it is not as used as StackOverFlow. Any help would be appreciated.

Link for the same issue on Matomo Forum -> https://forum.matomo.org/t/firebase-import-data-for-app-mobile/59819

There is no automated way to map your custom events or dimensions manually.
You need to manually map your customEvent:firebase_event_origin to a custom dimension when you configure the importer.
Unsupported GA Dimensions
A event would probably be in the action scope, and dimension in a visit scope. Just be aware of the scope limitation:

Custom dimensions with scope=item is ignored during import as Matomo currently supports visit and action level dimensions only.

Limitations when importing google-analytics data
Depending on if you're using Matomo Cloud or On-prem, Matomo has 5 to 15 CustomDimensions per default, if you're expecting more than that, you would probably have to increase that number as well.
How do I add more than the default 5 custom dimensions?
